# Dealing with kbhit in child process with redirected stdin

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've written a program that starts another process and redirects its standard I/O to pipes using the windows API (CreateProcess, CreatePipe, etc.)

The program should start multiple different console programs and communicate with them using stdio.

This was all working well (I could write to the stdin of the process and read from the process using the pipes) until I tried to start and communicate with a program that was using kbhit.

To simplify it what that program I'd like to start does with the standard input:

```
while(1)
{
    if(kbhit())
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        //do something with line
    }
    Sleep(100);
 }
```

The result is that fgets gets never called because kbhit doesn't return true even though I've written to the pipe that I've redirected stdin to. I know that because I've debugged into the other program. I've tried to remove the call of kbhit and then it does work but I can't change that code.

Is there a way to send something to the process so that that kbhit in the child process returns true?

Comment: I suppose `kbhit` reads the keyboard directly instead of reading via stdin. Why do you need `kbhit` here? Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: The other program that I didn't make uses kbhit and I can't change that

Comment: `kbhit()` is not a standard function in C++.   You'll need to read the documentation for the compiler/library used to build the "other program" in order to know how to interact with it - assuming that is even possible.

Comment: `_kbhit` read from console ( `CONIN$` device). it ignore stdin. what you write to stdin will be ignored

Comment: Is there no way to write something there?

Comment: you need use `WriteConsoleInput` and when you use shared console with child. for example `if (HANDLE hcon = CreateFileW(L"CONIN$", FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0)) { INPUT_RECORD ir = {KEY_EVENT, { TRUE, 1, VK_ESCAPE, MapVirtualKey(VK_ESCAPE, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), {1}}}; ULONG n; WriteConsoleInput(hcon, &ir, sizeof(ir), &n); CloseHandle(hcon); }`

Answer (score 2):

The [`_kbhit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx) function checks the **console** for a recent keystroke. it never check stdin, but open `CONIN$` (console input) and read always from here.

so redirect stdin here nothing give. if we share same console with child we can use [`WriteConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleinput) for this task. example for write string to child:

```
void write_to_conin(PCWSTR msg)
{
    if (ULONG len = (ULONG)wcslen(msg))
    {
        if (INPUT_RECORD* lpBuffer = new INPUT_RECORD[len])
        {
            INPUT_RECORD* pir = lpBuffer;
            ULONG n = len;
            do 
            {
                WCHAR UnicodeChar = *msg++;
                WORD wVirtualKeyCode = UnicodeChar;
                DWORD dwControlKeyState = CAPSLOCK_ON;

                if ((USHORT)(UnicodeChar - 'a') <= (USHORT)('z' - 'a'))
                {
                    dwControlKeyState = 0;
                    wVirtualKeyCode &= ~0x20;
                }

                pir->Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
                pir->Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = dwControlKeyState;
                pir->Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
                pir->Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = UnicodeChar;
                pir->Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = wVirtualKeyCode;
                pir->Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = (WORD)MapVirtualKey(wVirtualKeyCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
                pir++->EventType = KEY_EVENT;
            } while (--n);

            HANDLE hcon = CreateFileW(L"CONIN$", FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

            if (hcon != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
            { 
                WriteConsoleInput(hcon, lpBuffer, len, &n); 
                CloseHandle(hcon); 
            }

            delete [] lpBuffer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. I've tried to use your code in various ways but I've only got it working by creating a wrapper process that calls the actual process.

Comment: @JimmyT., you have to be attached to the same console. If you have a GUI app, you'll need to either call `AttachConsole(child_pid)` or, more simply, call `AllocConsole` beforehand for the child to inherit your console.

Comment: This kind of problem will be easier to handle with the new ConPTY system that will be available in the Fall update of Windows 10. ConPTY provides an I/O channel to a conhost.exe instance. The intended audience is an alternate console application such as ConEmu, generating and consuming UTF-8 virtual terminal sequences. But this will work equally well for a pexpect-like library that interacts with a console application.

Comment: The problem is that I need to start and communicate with multiple process so I can't have them all share the same console, that's why the need for the wrapper process that provides separate consoles for each process instance.

Comment: @JimmyT. yes, how i write in answer - *if we share same console with child*